# gettimeofday() returns negative value some times

Tags: linux, gettimeofday

I am getting negative values sometimes for below code.
I don't understand this.Can any one explain why it would happen.

```
int64_t gettimelocal()
{
    struct timeval Time;
    if(-1 == gettimeofday(&Time,NULL))
    {
        perror("gettimeofday");
    }
    // get time in micro seconds 
    return ((Time.tv_sec * 1000000) + Time.tc_usec);
}
```

Comment: Please format your question much better by editing it. It is unreadable! Use lines starting with at least four spaces for code.

Comment: `(Time.tv_sec * 1000000)` <-- possible integer overflow, depending on your platform.

Comment: how do you display it? with %d? try %ld or sth similar.

Comment: sorry it was typo mistake. i am using Time.tv_usec only. perror("gettimeofday"); wont show any error.

Comment: I display by using "%"PRId64". Why it is not overflowing all the time?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info and use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

To be safe, you should initialize `Time`. When `getttimeofday` fails, you should return after the `perror`. So try:

```
int64_t gettimelocal() {
   struct timeval Time = {0,0};
   if(-1 == gettimeofday(&Time,NULL)) {
     perror("gettimeofday");
     return -1;
   }
   // get time in micro seconds 
   return (((int64_t)Time.tv_sec * 1000000) + Time.tv_usec);
}
```

At last, are you sure that the multiplication does not overflow? You want a cast to be sure the multiplication is done in 64 bits.

Actually, I would suggest using `double` floating point with [clock_gettime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) like this:

```
static inline double my_clock_time (clockid_t cid) {
  struct timespec ts = { 0, 0 };
  if (clock_gettime (cid, &ts))
     return NAN;
  else
    return (double) ts.tv_sec + 1.0e-9 * ts.tv_nsec;
}
```

and call `my_clock_time(CLOCK_REALTIME)` like

```
 printf ("now %.5f\n", my_clock_time(CLOCK_REALTIME));
```

Read *carefully* [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Don't expect nanosecond accuracy!

Compile your code with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`) and perhaps [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)